# Android authentication against Spring Boot API not working

Tags: android, spring-boot, auth0

I have a Spring Boot back end API using Auth0 JWT authentication and currently have two clients for it, a Vue SPA and an Android app. The Vue SPA works fine. It uses an SPA Application type in Auth0, and the authentication mechanism uses an Audience, like so:

```
 {
    "domain": "mycompany.auth0.com",
    "clientId": "mySPAclientID",
    "audience": "https://myaudience.mycompany.com"
}
```

I figured I'd be able to do something similar in Android, so I created a Native Application type in my Auth0 Dashboard, downloaded the corresponding quickstart, and attempted to authenticate. I am, of course, able to authenticate against Auth0 and get a JWT back, but the JWT does not work against my Spring Boot API, which is designated by my https://myaudience.mycompany.com audience and which my Spring Boot security config expects to be present in the JWT. My first thought was that I could simply add the audience to the login action in the Android app:

```
WebAuthProvider.login(auth0)
                .withScheme("demo")
                .withAudience(String.format("https://%s/userinfo", getString(R.string.com_auth0_domain)))
                .withAudience("https://myaudience.mycompany.com") // added this
                .start(this, new AuthCallback() { ... }
```

But this doesn't work. When I parse the returned JWT, the audience portion does not contain the expected block. It should look like this:

```
"aud": [
    "https://myaudience.mycompany.com",
    "https://mycompany.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ]
```

But instead it looks like this:

`"aud": "myNativeClientID"`

It's also missing the scope element entirely. What's the correct way to make this work? Do I need a new Auth0 API, which would require a new Spring Boot security mechanism? Or is there something simple I'm missing in the login request? Or some config I'm missing in my Auth0 Native Application? I've been through all the relevant documentation and nothing works. I'm not sure how to proceed, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With a helpful nudge by an Auth0 employee, I realized that I'd confused the Auth0 ID token with the access token. In Auth0, ID tokens are *always* issued as JWTs, but they can't be used to access Auth0 APIs, only access tokens can do that. The trouble is that unless you specify an "audience" in your login request, the access token is of a simple token format like this:

```
1v-QyDrPaJ5rOUBOk3g_0HtEwtN4C-4U
```

But when you add an audience (ie an Auth0 API, which is in turn referenced in your back end, whatever it may be, in my case Spring Boot), the access token becomes a JWT with all the requisite audiences and scopes (by default the scope is limited to openapi, I believe).

So because the access token was not a JWT (since I hadn't yet added the audience when I first examined the login response), I dismissed it, and was using the ID token, which as I mentioned can't be used to gain access to an Auth0 API. Once I reverted back to using the access token JWT, everything worked as expected.

Accepting this as an answer in case it helps anyone in the future.